# javascript 3D points to 2D

Tags: javascript, projection, perspective

Does anyone know the correct formula to transform 3D points into 2D perspective projection

I have a cube that is located:
var vertices = [
            new Point3D(-1,1,-1),
            new Point3D(1,1,-1),
            new Point3D(1,-1,-1),
            new Point3D(-1,-1,-1),

```
        new Point3D(-1,1,1),
        new Point3D(1,1,1),
        new Point3D(1,-1,1),
        new Point3D(-1,-1,1)
    ];
```

These points are connected with faces...

How do I get a matrix that will have the correct 2D coordinates if the camera is in Point3D(0,0,-4)

Comment: That would also depend on the direction the camera is looking at, the projection type, view frustum, various other things. What is it exactly that you're trying to do, and are you using some sort of library already?

Comment: I assume that if camera is in (0,0,-4) it's looking directly to the center of the screen. No, I don't use libraries. I know that there are functions in glMatrix mat4 class but I want to write my own, I just don't know how to transform these points.

So again, if I draw these points on paper I will get a cube around the center of the coordinate system. The camera is looking at this cube from the center but is backed away 4 units. That means there is no angle.

Comment: In that case this is just too broad. There are many good resources online about linear algebra and 3D transforms, much better than what anybody would bother typing up on SO, you should go read one of those.

Comment: I did found formulas to get x' and y' but they just aren't working.

x' = x * ((z-zc) / z)
y' = y *((z-zc) / z)